# Use of contractions

Tags: grammar

Which of these two options is correct.
**Don't you live in the UK?. Now you can watch the live news
Do you not live in the UK?. Now you can watch the live news**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends how formal you want to be. Your first example is what would be commonly heard and spoken, but the second achieves the goal of avoiding contractions in proper writing.